# APIM Inbound Policy - Use Set-Body to append an XML element containing child elements at the root level

Tags: xml, azure-api-management, apim

UPS's api requires credentials in the request body it receives in an element called AccessRequest.
Via Azure API Management, I need to inject this into the Inbound Policy along with the existing body content (TrackingRequest).
I can save the complete AccessRequest content in Azure Key Vault and inject it in one go using {{AccessRequest}}.

Here is an example of what I want POSTing to their API.

```
<AccessRequest>
    <AccessLicenseNumber>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</AccessLicenseNumber>
    <UserId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</UserId>
    <Password>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</Password>
</AccessRequest>
<TrackRequest>
    <Request>
        <TransactionReference>
            <CustomerContext>Your Test Case Summary Description</CustomerContext>
        </TransactionReference>
        <RequestAction>Track</RequestAction>
        <RequestOption>activity</RequestOption>
    </Request>
    <TrackingNumber>1Z6xxxxxxxxxxxxx</TrackingNumber>
</TrackRequest>
```

My attempt.....

```
<set-body>@{ 
var requestBody = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);
requestBody [\"Content-Type\"] = \"application/xml\";
requestBody.Append(\"{{AccessRequest}}\");
return requestBody.ToString();
}</set-body>
```

Hoping this would work but it fails on

```
Content:
{"error":{"code":"ValidationError","message":"One or more fields 
contain incorrect values:","details": 
[{"code":"ValidationError","target":"set-body","message":"Error in 
element 'set-body' on line 3, column 38: 'JObject' does not contain 
a definition for 'Append' and the best extension method overload 
'Enumerable.Append<string>(IEnumerable<string>, string)' requires a 
receiver of type 'IEnumerable<string>'"}]}}
```

Comment: Do you know difference between an HTTP header and body data?  You want to send XML but your code is creating a JSON object.

Comment: Was hoping to use JObject to edit the content, and for some reason thought forcing the Content-Type to xml would convert it to xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a named variable which is having below value in it.

```xml
<AccessRequest>
   <AccessLicenseNumber>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</AccessLicenseNumber>
    <UserId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</UserId>
    <Password>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</Password>
</AccessRequest>
```

I am using this below given policy to add AccessRequest element at the top of existing body content of TrackRequest.

```xml
<inbound>
    <base  />
    <set-variable  name="accessRequest"  value="{{AccessRequest}}"  />
    <set-body>@{
        var trackRequest = context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
        var accessRequest = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("accessRequest");
        var mergedRequest = $@"{accessRequest}{trackRequest}";
        return mergedRequest;
    }</set-body>
    <set-header  name="Content-Type"  exists-action="override">
        <value>application/xml</value>
    </set-header>
</inbound>
```

I am able get the expected output.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you. Any recommendation on where to find info on this topic?